# How to use awk to get a special field from a file?

Tags: linux, awk, filter

This is the output of ifconfig, I want to get only the number 78 (4th octet of the ip address) using awk

```
ns33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.78  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e698:d8b3:62ad:a784  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:0d:32:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2644  bytes 3395138 (3.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 897  bytes 67558 (67.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: what have you tired?  ... what were the results? ... please add that to your post, not in a comment

Comment: what if `ifconfig` displays info for multiple interfaces? are you looking for the 4th inet/tuple for all interfaces, the 1st interface, or a specific interface? please update the question to include an `ifconfig` output with (at least) 2 interfaces, the expected result, and the code you've tried so far

Comment: Perhaps a more modern approach would be to query the `--json` output of an `ip address` command? something like `ip --json address show dev ns33 | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info[] | select(.family == "inet") | .local | split(".")[-1]'`

Answer (score 1):

Something like can should the work:

```
awk '$1=="inet"{split($2,a,"."); print a[4]}'
```

The idea is to get only the line with first word `inet` and split, using dot as delimiter.

But as mentioned in comment you should do some filtering if you have more than one interface